# Rounded corner <select> drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to curve select drop down box option.

So far, I have achieved a styled effect within the drop down box itself (the box that drops down with the options) by applying certain styles to the select tag but I want to give `border-radius` in options.

Here is the css I have used so far any suggestion for using JS here you can suggest me:

```css
.formRight select {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #E8E8E8 inset;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 0 0 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 110px;
}
```

```html
<p class="formRight">
<span style="padding-right:100px">Lead Type: </span>

    <select id="leadType" class="box2" name="lead_type">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get very little control on the style of the dropdown of a native `select` control, and you certainly can't add rounded borders to it.

To achieve what you need you would have to use a third party dropdown plugin which replaces the `select` and its `option` elements with plain HTML, such as [Select2](https://select2.github.io/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I saw that but in jsfiddle that not working. can u suggest me which class I have to use here?  https://jsfiddle.net/lemonkazi/b92u05a8/

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to style the surrounding box of the options just by using css. The only way you can manage that is the create a faux select input of your own using divs and styling them as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

There are no cross-browser CSS proprieties to style `<option>` tag, if you want to make options corners round you should use SelectBoxIt jQuery plugin for example.

http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/